# typescript doesn't exclude node_modules while compile

Tags: typescript, yarn-workspaces

I had this error every time when I try to build my code, And also I forgot to tell I'm using yarn workspace and I'm excluding node_modules in all tsconfig

Actual ERROR:

```
$ rimraf ./dist && tsc
../../node_modules/graphql-toolkit/dist/esnext/utils/validate-documents.d.ts:7:115 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

7 export declare const validateGraphQlDocuments: (schema: GraphQLSchema, documentFiles: DocumentFile[]) => readonly LoadDocumentError[];
                                                                                                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~


../../node_modules/graphql-toolkit/dist/esnext/utils/validate-documents.d.ts:7:132 - error TS1005: ',' expected.

7 export declare const validateGraphQlDocuments: (schema: GraphQLSchema, documentFiles: DocumentFile[]) => readonly LoadDocumentError[];

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I can't make it work even though I exclude node_modules and skipLibCheck:true But Nothing seems to be helpful

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["dom", "es6", "es2017", "esnext", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

I want to compile it with error free and exclude .d.ts files in node_modules

Comment: You probably just need to upgrade to a TypeScript version >= 3.4 (where that `readonly` syntax exists).

Comment: I use typescript v3.8.3 - but face the same problem